# multiple http get but different arguments

Tags: node.js

Following is my code to get all the products.

```
app.get('/product', function(request,response){

var query="SELECT p.productid, p.categoryId, p.productName, p.specification, c.categoryName"+ 
" FROM tblproduct p inner join tblcategory c on p.categoryid=c.categoryid order by p.productName";

Mysql.query(query)
    .then(function(results){
        response.json({result:results});
}).catch(function(err){
    reject(err);
});
```

});

Now i want to get product based on product id.

What should be my http get code.

My URL to access a single product will be localhost/product/productid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
    app.get('/products/:id', function(req, res) {

       var productId = req.params.id;
    });
```